# How to replace dropdown on template plugin to buttons in tinymce 5?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

I tried to duplicate the template plugin folders and I want to have the dropdown replaced with buttons.

[image: replacing the dropdown into buttons]

Answer (score 0):

The question Lacks enough context but TintMCE Has documentation which answers your question (As I understand it) here
[enter link description here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/code/)

Also depends on which plugins you want etc

Edit:
Add options to TinyMCE int he init like so:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: 'link image table',
  contextmenu: 'link image table'
});
```

Comment: What I mean is instead of a dropdown on the template plugin dialog box. It will display as buttons and I can't have a click event on it.

Currently, when you click on the template plugin it will display a dropdown for the options of the templates and its preview below.